# Error when executing query with SQLite in C++

Tags: sqlite

Okay so i have 2 methods in my code: one to create a database and one to insert records. Here they are:

```
void DatabaseManager::insert_entry_into_database() {
ostringstream ss;
int choice;

do {
    cout << "Press 1 to add a teacher or 2 for student";
    cin >> choice;
} while (choice != 1 && choice != 2);       

if (choice == 1) {
    Teacher t;
    ss << "INSERT INTO Teachers ('" << t.get_firstName() << "', '" << t.get_lastName() << "', " << t.get_NID() 
        << ", " << t.get_avg_horarium() << ");";
}

const string tmp = ss.str();
const char *query = tmp.c_str();

cout << query;

sqlite3_open("Database.sqlite", &database);
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
    cout << "A new record has been added to the database!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Error adding new record!";
}   
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(database); 
}

void DatabaseManager::create_database() {
sqlite3_open("Database.sqlite", &database);

char * query = "CREATE TABLE Students (firstName STRING, lastName STRING, NID BIGINT, grade DOUBLE);";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
    cout << "Empty database with students created!" << endl;
}

query = "CREATE TABLE Teachers (firstName STRING, lastName STRING, NID BIGINT, avg_horarium INT);";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
    cout << "Empty database with teachers created!" << endl;
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

I test them in the main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
DatabaseManager m;
m.create_database();
m.insert_entry_into_database();
return 0;
}
```

The create table queries seem to be succesful and the confirmation message shows on the console but the insert query is treated as invalid. I've added a cout << query call to make sure it's correct and it is a hundred percent valid. What's wrong with this?

---

The select method

```
vector<vector<string>> DatabaseManager::select_entry() {
vector<vector<string>> results;
sqlite3_open("Database.sqlite", &database);

char* query = "SELECT firstName FROM Teachers WHERE firstName = 'Ivan';";
cout << query;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
    int cols = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
    int result = 0;

    while (true) {
        result = sqlite3_step(statement);

        if (result == SQLITE_ROW) {
            cout << "test"; 
            vector<string> values;
            for (int i=0; i<cols; i++) {
                cout << (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                values.push_back((char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i));
            }
            results.push_back(values);
        }
        else break;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    string error = sqlite3_errmsg(database);
    if(error != "not an error") cout << query << " " << error << endl;

    return results;
}
```

}

Comment: "treated as invalid" is rather vague. What is the error message returned by [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)?

Comment: it says no such table: Teachers. actually as I think, I may be using some test database, beacause I haven't executed "CREATE DATABASE" query. so actually my question would be how to create a constant database and use it in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [valid syntax for an INSERT statement](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) is either

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Col1, Col2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
```

You have omitted `VALUES`, so SQLite thinks that the stuff inside the parentheses is the list of column names.

---

The database file is created automatically by `sqlite3_open`.

---

You need to call [`sqlite3_step`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) to actually execute your commands.

Comment: yes, I really had omitted VALUES but after i added it, it's still the same situation...

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow does not allow me to put `<blink>` tags around the last sentence of my answer ...

Comment: i wrote it in my last post... it says "no such table: Teachers" (sqlite3_errmsg).

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` command is never executed because you never call `sqlite3_step`.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine, now the insert queries work, but now i have a problem when selecting data using SELECT. I found a method from the internet and modified it a little but it doesn't work. I updated my first post with that method. It executes this line if(error != "not an error") cout << query << " " << error << endl; but error is just an empty string now. 
Also, the query passes the (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) condition but doesn't retrieve any data into the vector and the result is an empty vector.

Comment: A different question is a different question.